# Using typescript with useRoute on react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to extract the params as follows using `useRoute` as follows.

```
  const route = useRoute();
  const { params } = route;
  const {
   id, name,
  } = params;
```

Everything works fine but the linter is highlighting `id` and `name`with the following error.

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object | undefined

How do I overcome this issue.

Answer (score 8):

`react-navigation` exports a couple utility types to make your life easier when using hooks and defining props for your own components. They depend on you first defining types for your navigators.

---

Lets say you have a stack with two screens, A and B. First define what params each of those takes:

```js
type StackParamsList = {
  A: undefined;
  B: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
}
```

For typing `useRoute` in your screen B:

```js
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

const route = useRoute<RouteProp<StackParamsList, 'B'>>();

route.params.id // OK
route.params.foo // error
```

Check the [Type checking with Typescript](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#type-checking-screens) article in react-navigation docs for more details and examples of typing other elements of your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my example for typescript:**

```js
// Route (index.ts)
// Route creation
    import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";

      PointScreen?:{
        myLogra:string,
        myBairro:string,
        myCidade:string,
        myEstado: string,
        myPais:string,
        myCep:string,
        myNum:string,
      } 

    };
    export type propsStack = NativeStackNavigationProp<propsNavigationStack >;

// -------------

    // AndressScreen (index.tsx)
    // Sends screen data to PointScreen
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { propsStack } from '../../components/Route';

  const navigation = useNavigation<propsStack>();

  const handleSelectPoint = () => {
   navigation.navigate('PointScreen', {
      myLogra: coletLogra,
      myBairro: coletBairro,
      myCidade: coletCidade,
      myEstado: coletEstado,
      myPais: coletPais,
      myCep: coletCep,
      myNum: coletNum,
      myID:id,
    })
  };

//--------- 

     // PointScreen (index.tsx)
     // Receives data from the screen AndressScreen
     import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
     import { propsStack, propsNavigationStack } from '../../components/Route';

        const navigation = useNavigation<propsStack>();
        const route = useRoute<RouteProp<propsNavigationStack, "PointScreen">>();

        useEffect(() => {
            setColetLogra(route?.params.myLogra)
            setColetNum(route?.params.myNum)
            setColetBairro(route?.params.myBairro)
            setColetCidade(route?.params.myCidade)
            setColetEstado(route?.params.myEstado)
            setColetCep(route?.params.myCep)
            setColetPais(route?.params.myPais)
        }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).